# What is the best way convert object keys from snake case to camel case and vice versa?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, object

I have a response from the server with the following structure:

```
{
    is_separate_page: true,
    is_blank_page: true,
    is_instructions_page: false,
    is_letter_paper: true,
    is_pressure_seal_paper: false,
    is_mask_ssn_on_letter_paper: true,
    is_mask_ssn_on_pressure_seal_paper: true,
    is_pdf_encrypted_on_letter_paper: false,
    is_pdf_encrypted_on_pressure_seal_paper: true
}
```

Then I do transform values into camel case syntax to store in my React component state using the following helper function:

```
// Destructuring approach

transformInitialCheckboxesState = data => {
        const {
            is_show_mask_ssn_field: isShowMaskSSNField,
            is_separate_page: isSeparatePage,
            is_blank_page: isBlankPage,
            is_instructions_page: isInstructionsPage,
            is_letter_paper: isLetterPaper,
            is_pressure_seal_paper: isPressureSealPaper,
            is_mask_ssn_on_letter_paper: isMaskSSNonLetterPaper,
            is_mask_ssn_on_pressure_seal_paper: isMaskSSNonPressureSealPaper,
            is_pdf_encrypted_on_letter_paper: isPDFEncryptedOnLetterPaper,
            is_pdf_encrypted_on_pressure_seal_paper: isPDFEncryptedOnPressureSealPaper,
        } = data

        return {
            isShowMaskSSNField,
            isSeparatePage,
            isBlankPage,
            isInstructionsPage,
            isLetterPaper,
            isPressureSealPaper,
            isMaskSSNonLetterPaper,
            isMaskSSNonPressureSealPaper,
            isPDFEncryptedOnLetterPaper,
            isPDFEncryptedOnPressureSealPaper,
        }
    }
```

For submitting values I should do the opposite operation for preparing keys in accordance with back-end needs:

```
    preparePayloadCheckboxesState = data => {
        const {
            isShowMaskSSNField: is_show_mask_ssn_field,
            isSeparatePage: is_separate_page,
            isBlankPage: is_blank_page,
            isInstructionsPage: is_instructions_page,
            isLetterPaper: is_letter_paper,
            isPressureSealPaper: is_pressure_seal_paper,
            isMaskSSNonLetterPaper: is_mask_ssn_on_letter_paper,
            isMaskSSNonPressureSealPaper: is_mask_ssn_on_pressure_seal_paper,
            isPDFEncryptedOnLetterPaper: is_pdf_encrypted_on_letter_paper,
            isPDFEncryptedOnPressureSealPaper: is_pdf_encrypted_on_pressure_seal_paper,
        } = data

        return {
            is_show_mask_ssn_field,
            is_separate_page,
            is_blank_page,
            is_instructions_page,
            is_letter_paper,
            is_pressure_seal_paper,
            is_mask_ssn_on_letter_paper,
            is_mask_ssn_on_pressure_seal_paper,
            is_pdf_encrypted_on_letter_paper,
            is_pdf_encrypted_on_pressure_seal_paper,
        }
    }
```

The question is: It looks very similar and repeatable on my point, what is the best and the most elegant way to reduce this code on your point?

Comment: Note that, often enough, "elegant" and "performant" are incompatible.

Comment: Hi, Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/73220750/11888809, you can do that with one line of code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want replace all the `_<alphabet>` with `<Uppercase Alphabet>`, you could loop through the [`entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) of the object and replace all the `_([a-z])` with the uppercase alphabet. Then use [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) to get a new object

```js
const fn = key => key.replace(/_([a-z])/g, (_, m) => m.toUpperCase())
const reverse_fn = key => key.replace(/[A-Z]/g, m => `_${m.toLowerCase()}`)

// trasnforms an object based on the replacer function provided
const trasnform = (o, replacer) =>
  Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(o).map(([k, v]) => [replacer(k), v])
  )

const input={is_separate_page:true,is_blank_page:true,is_instructions_page:false,is_letter_paper:true,is_pressure_seal_paper:false,is_mask_ssn_on_letter_paper:true,is_mask_ssn_on_pressure_seal_paper:true,is_pdf_encrypted_on_letter_paper:false,is_pdf_encrypted_on_pressure_seal_paper:true} ,
     reverseInput ={isSeparatePage:true,isBlankPage:true,isInstructionsPage:false,isLetterPaper:true,isPressureSealPaper:false,isMaskSsnOnLetterPaper:true,isMaskSsnOnPressureSealPaper:true,isPdfEncryptedOnLetterPaper:false,isPdfEncryptedOnPressureSealPaper:true};

// forward transform
console.log(
  trasnform(input, fn)
)

// reverse transform
console.log(
  trasnform(reverseInput, reverse_fn)
)
```

The reverse mapping would be similar. You just need to replace all the uppercase letters with `"_" + <lower case letter>`

```
key.replace(/A-Z/g, m => "_" + m.toLowerCase()
```

---

**Note**: If `Object.fromEntries()` is not supported, you could [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) the keys of the object and create a new object:

```js
const o = {
  is_separate_page: true,
  is_blank_page: true,
  is_instructions_page: false,
  is_letter_paper: true,
  is_pressure_seal_paper: false,
  is_mask_ssn_on_letter_paper: true,
  is_mask_ssn_on_pressure_seal_paper: true,
  is_pdf_encrypted_on_letter_paper: false,
  is_pdf_encrypted_on_pressure_seal_paper: true
}

const trasnform = (o) => 
  Object.keys(o).reduce((acc, k) => {
    const newKey = k.replace(/_([a-z])/g, (_, m) => m.toUpperCase());
    acc[newKey] = o[k];
    return acc;
  }, {})

console.log(trasnform(o))
```

Comment: (Or if you already have a dependency on something like lodash, use `mapKeys`.)

Comment: And of course `k.replace(/([A-Z])/g, (m) => '_' + m.toLowerCase())` for the reverse case, which will not work if there are any extraneous capital letters.

Comment: @ScottSauyet I just added that :). Also, capturing group is not required for the reverse case

Comment: Timing! :-)  And yes, that's right about the capture group.

Comment: Of course this all breaks down when you try to make it work with abbreviations, such as the `"_ssn_"` to `SSN` and `"_pdf_"` to `"PDF"` in the example. But it gets you most of the way there.

Comment: @JDB well spotted. That's a trade-off OP would've to make

Comment: Thank you guys, like this approach:)

Answer (score 0):

You could create your mapping object and transform functions:

```
const mapping = {
    "is_show_mask_ssn_field" : "isShowMaskSSNField",
    "is_separate_page": "isSeparatePage",
    ... other properties
}

const fromServer = (data) => {
    let obj = {};
    for (var prop in data) {
        var realName = mapping[prop];
        if (realName) {
            obj[realName] = data[prop];
        }
    }
    return obj;
}

const toServer = (data) => {
    let obj = {};
    for (var serverName in mapping) {
        var realName = mapping[serverName];
        if (data.hasOwnProperty(realName)) {
            obj[serverName] = data[realName];
        }
    }
    return obj;
}
```

So you just call `fromServer` on data once you receive it from endpoint and `toServer` on your model before sending it to server.